# Smoothing a signal so that it becomes differentiable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I got a signal which shows a relative shape, i.e. the local maxima are actually 0 and the local minima are the true distortion.

I managed to restore something close to the original signal but the result has become non differentiable since I decomposed it into cosine functions with Amplitude and Frequency depending on (x) in a non differentiable way.

My question is can I force my signal to be differentiable in a simple way?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train_fit = pd.read_csv('train_fit.csv')

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(24,9))
ax.fill_between(train_fit['x'],train_fit['H_A'],-train_fit['H_A'],alpha=.1)
#ax.plot(train_0['x'],train_0['H']) #the orignal signal
ax.plot(train_fit['x'],train_fit['H_fit'])
ax.plot(train_fit['x'],train_fit['H_fit_adj'])
ax.axhline(0,color='k',linestyle=':')
ax.legend(loc='upper left')

ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.plot(train_fit['x'],train_fit['H_f'],color='gray',alpha=.5)
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')

plt.show()
```

[image]

sample data is here: https://pastebin.com/ViwUDTx8

Comment: `train_0` is not defined

Comment: a simple/dirty way is to draw windows around the kinks, cut the data from within them, and then interpolate it back without the kinks. That's probably accurate enough for government work. You can also locate the kinks by thresholding the derivative

Comment: Thanks I solved it using spikes in the second differential and replacing the surroundings with a cubic interpolation.
If you want you can draw up an awnser and I'll accept it